# POST request successful but database not updated when submitting object

Tags: javascript, json

I'm creating a server-side React app on an Express server. The app will be the front-end of a site that uses Wordpress as a back-end. The front-end fetches and posts content through the Wordpress REST API.

I'm having trouble updating a user's info when it's stored as an object. Here's the POST request I make on submitting the user's profile form:

```
export const updateUserInfo = () => async ( dispatch, getState, api ) => {    

    const postUserInfo = {
        "personal_info": {
            "firstname": "John", 
            "lastname": "Doe"
        }
    }

    await api.post( '/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1', postUserInfo, requestAuth ); 

}
```

From the inspector I can see that the request is successful (200 code) and the payload is correct, but the user's first and last names in the database are not updated.

If I try to post a simple key-value pair rather than an object, the database is updated just fine:

```
// This works! 

export const updateUserInfo = () => async ( dispatch, getState, api ) => {    

    const postUserInfo = {
        "slug": "john-doe"
    }

    await api.post( '/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1', postUserInfo, requestAuth ); 

}
```

Here's how I register the `personal_info` field:

```
public function get_user_personal_info() {
    register_rest_field( 'user', 'personal_info', array(
        'get_callback' => array( $this, 'get_user_personal_info_callback' ),
        'update_callback' => null,
        'schema' => null 
    ));        
}     
public function get_user_personal_info_callback( $user ) {  

    $userID = $user[ 'id' ]; 
    $getFirstName = get_user_meta( $userID, 'rcp_user_first', true ); 
    $firstName = ( $getFirstName ) ? $getFirstName : null;
    $getLastName = get_user_meta( $userID, 'rcp_user_last', true ); 
    $lastName = ( $getLastName ) ? $getLastName : null;

    return array(
        'firstname' => $firstName,
        'lastname' => $lastName,
    );           

}
```

Comment: what does REST API actually expects?

Comment: In the first code, you used an object in object! does API work with this input correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure... I'm not big on APIs... The `personal_info` I'm trying to update is a custom REST field I've registered—I've update my answer with the code. Should I change the `schema` to make it work with objects?